# open layers 3 - Namespace "ol" already declared error on startup

Tags: openlayers-3, google-closure-compiler

I am using instructions from [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) on how to get started with open layers and I got the error: `Namespace "ol" already declared - source ol-debug.js` and the error 
`this.Va is not a function - source ol.js`

I am pretty sure I have included the ol.js, ol-debug.js and ol.css files properly in my index.html.

[Link](http://openlayers.org/download/) to open layers js and css files.

This is the relevant part from `ol-debug.js` file -

```
/**
 * Defines a namespace in Closure.
 *
 * A namespace may only be defined once in a codebase. It may be defined using
 * goog.provide() or goog.module().
 *
 * The presence of one or more goog.provide() calls in a file indicates
 * that the file defines the given objects/namespaces.
 * Provided symbols must not be null or undefined.
 *
 * In addition, goog.provide() creates the object stubs for a namespace
 * (for example, goog.provide("goog.foo.bar") will create the object
 * goog.foo.bar if it does not already exist).
 *
 * Build tools also scan for provide/require/module statements
 * to discern dependencies, build dependency files (see deps.js), etc.
 *
 * @see goog.require
 * @see goog.module
 * @param {string} name Namespace provided by this file in the form
 *     "goog.package.part".
 */
goog.provide = function(name) {
  if (goog.isInModuleLoader_()) {
    throw Error('goog.provide can not be used within a goog.module.');
  }
  if (!COMPILED) {
    // Ensure that the same namespace isn't provided twice.
    // A goog.module/goog.provide maps a goog.require to a specific file
    if (goog.isProvided_(name)) {
      throw Error('Namespace "' + name + '" already declared.');
    }
  }

  goog.constructNamespace_(name);
};
```

Comment: `I am pretty sure I have included the ol.js, ol-debug.js and ol.css` Include either ol.js or  ol-debug.js , not both of them

Comment: Well, that was a gotcha! Thanks.

Comment: haha. gotcha ... glad to help dude

Comment: Do you want to provide your own answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare either `ol.js` or `ol-debug.js`, not both of them. The error is coming from the fact that you're declaring both of them and it is creating a namespace conflict.